# I want to send each http request using Jmeter using different public IP

Tags: proxy, jmeter, ip, httprequest, vpn

I already tried sending request by Assigning different local ip but still I get 429 too many request error from server after 10-15 continuous request. So is there any chance to iterate different public IP to send requests

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to specify a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) for the request, the setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

however you will have to come up with the list of proxies and parameterize it using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)